# In Eclipse, how to make Shift+Enter to not send a commit immediately?

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

In Eclipse, how to make Shift+Enter to not send a commit immediately?

In most editting contexts in software (editors, browsers, etc.), Shift+Enter makes a hard linebreak, but in Eclipse when you compose a commit message before making commit to a version control system, hitting Shift+Enter will make the commit immediately. Is there a way to override this sometimes-inconvenient behavior?

Answer (score 4):

I'm putting this here because it's not apparent where to reply to the previous answer.

These instructions are incorrect. Ctrl+Shift+L twice does not open my preferences. You must then navigate to General>Keys. Then under the binding column you can find Shift+Enter but it is only set to "Insert Line Below Current Line". Unbinding this command does not change behaviour when committing.

Comment: Indeed, "Insert Line Below Current Line" is actually the behaviour we would expect; instead, the commit dialog is somehow overriding that.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to disable this command.

- Hit the **CTRL+SHIFT+L** twice.
- Preferances window will be opened.
- Go to **Shift+Enter** in Binding column.
- Click on **Unbind Command** button to disable it.

Comment: As Craig Pemberton mentioned, this won't change the aforementioned unwanted behaviour.